# how to find the source of query having opaque transform hint in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find the source of opaque transform query because its taking to much time.

```
SELECT /*+ OPAQUE_TRANSFORM */ "column1","column1" 
from table_name;
```

Comment: Most likely, it's part of a query run on a different database that connects to your database via a database link where Oracle is automatically injecting the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any source is available for `opaque transform` in oracle, this hint automatically  appears in the internal SQL in remote server generated by the distributed query using the format of `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM`.

For example when you execute `exec sql_explain('insert into table1 select * from
table2@DBLINK','TYPICAL');`

Output will be:

```
SELECT /*+ OPAQUE_TRANSFORM */ "COLUMN_NAME" FROM "TABLE2" 
"TABLE2" (accessing 'ORA11R2' )
```